# Batch file that opens a program, wait 5 seconds, then press 2 keyboard keys

Tags: batch-file

I have Windows 10 Pro.

I need a .bat file that will open the TeamSpeak.exe, wait 5 seconds, and then press the hotkey "INSERT" and then press the combination "CTRL + DELETE" in order to mute my microfone and my sound. I searched this code and it did not work for me:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
start ts3client_win64.exe -nc
goto :EOF
@end
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 4000 > nul
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{INSERT}");
```

When I run in CMD, this is the error msg:

*C:\Program Files\TeamSpeak 3 Client\test.bat(1, 6) Compilation error from Microsoft JScript: ';' expected*

Comment: You would be best of using VBS to do this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Powershell (see [Provide Input to Applications with PowerShell](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/10/provide-input-to-applications-with-powershell/))

```
add-type -AssemblyName microsoft.VisualBasic
add-type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
start-process "C:/path/to/TeamSpeak.exe"
start-sleep -Seconds 5
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("TeamSpeak")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{INSERT}")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{DELETE}")
```

Worked for me with Notepad and a file as argument.